# mysql C API bulk inserts

Tags: mysql, c, database

I want to send bulk updates to the MySQL using C APIs. If any of these failed I need to know which one is failed. What is the option for this? Can I use the multiple statement command in my_query() or can I use multiple inserts? In both of these cases I failed to find how to retrieve the exact row which is failed (due to duplicate key)

Answer (score 0):

If bulk inserts are used, the command fails if insertion of one of the records fails. In this case no lines will be inserted, and you will get an error with the text that contains the duplicate value.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO table10 VALUES (1), (2), (3);
ok
INSERT INTO table10 VALUES (4), (1), (2);
Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Also, you can use an IGNORE option in the [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) statement to ignore all errors.

Comment: Thanks Devart. When I use IGNORE all the duplicate entries came as duplicate. I can now know the count of duplicates,but still don't know which are duplicates.

Comment: Please provide table structure (CREATE TABLE statement) and criteria to find out duplicates.